# TypeFace - Fragment Crash my app on Device

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am attempting to use a custom font for a TextView in Fragment, but my app crash on phone (4.4.2), however there is not showing any bug in Android Studio

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/androidnation_b.ttf");
    TextView txt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt.setTypeface(font);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);
}
```

When I comment those three lines before return inflater app works.
I am looking for a solution for almost a week but nothing helped!

Here's my path for ttf: Project -> src/main/assets/fonts/androidnation_b.ttf

I have in fragment_layout view with that id (textView1)
Any idea how to solve this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution do it like

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);

Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/androidnation_b.ttf");

TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txt.setTypeface(font);

return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/androidnation_b.ttf");
TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txt.setTypeface(font);

return view;
```